# How does exhaust affect certain abilities?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are several abilities that deal damage after an amount of time (Zed's ultimate, Karthus' ultimate, Zileans' time bomb etc). While waiting for the damage to trigger, if the champion is exhausted will the damage be reduced by 40%?

Comment: May already have an answer [Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155043/league-of-legends-damage-modifiers-while-channeling/155060#155060)

Comment: Oh, sorry for duplicate question. Lacked in searching, it seems.

Comment: Well it's a good question. Somehow the questions also are different (it's not a dupe IMO) but the answers are basically the same.

Answer (score 2):

Exhaust affects the damage when it hits.

So if you exhaust Karthus (2.5sec), then he casts his ult (3sec) the utl will impact with **full** damage and is not affected by exhaust.

So if Karthus casts his ult (3sec) and you exhaust him when he already channled for 1 sec the utl will impact with **reduced** damage.

Since exhaust reduces Movement Speed and Attack Speed by 30%, enemies Armor and Magic Resist by 10, and their damage dealt by 40%. **Heal** (Zilean ult) **is not affected**.

Comment: I think the OP was referring to Zilean's time bomb. Also Zilean's ult is not considered a heal, I do not believe the effect has an official name as it is not a status effect, you are just invulnerable for a short time and return with more health once you reach 0hp. The same can be said for Guardian Angel.